# Finding sublists in lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a matrix of booleans. Most rows look like this

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

but some of them look like this

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

I want to find the ones that have a 0 followed by a 1. How can I do this? My naive attempt is to try

```
c(0, 1) %in% my_list
```

but that returns

```
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

since both 0 and 1 are in the list. D'oh! Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about looking at diffs instead

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
1 %in% diff(x)
```

Then create a function, and `apply` it to the rows of your matrix.

Comment: Oh, it's so brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably pretty pointless as the other answer is already pretty quick, but this will scale better for very big matrices to identify the rows you want. E.g.:

```
no  <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
yes <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

m <- rbind(no,yes,no,yes,no,yes,yes)
#           1   2  3   4  5   6   7 
# result should thus be c(2,4,6,7)

col(t(m[,-1]))[diff(t(m))==1]
#[1] 2 4 6 7
```

1 million row matrix benchmark:

```
m <- m[sample(1:2,1000000,replace=TRUE),]
system.time(apply(m, 1, function(x) 1 %in% diff(x) ))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  12.09    0.00   12.09 
system.time(col(t(m[,-1]))[diff(t(m))==1])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.61    0.05    0.65
```

Alternative suggested by @MatthewLundberg, which is probably a really good balance of  speed and readability.

```
system.time(apply(diff(t(m))==1, 2, any))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.85    0.00    1.84
```

Comment: Indexing `col` this way is very much like applying `any` to the columns:  `apply(diff(t(m))==1, 2, any)`.  How does this compare?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - that method is a lot quicker than the other `apply`, but still about thrice the time of my original attempt. It is a lot more readable however.

Comment: It's a refactoring of what you wrote with the indexing of `col`, not an original idea.  I really like this approach of yours, and wonder where it might be used in general (perhaps wrapped in a function so that it is more readable).